# TFS add folder and files to checking automatically

Tags: tfs, version-control

I've have a Solution with Projects I can add to TFS and everything works fine. But I have a background task which generates some yml files outside of my project

## Structure:

- sln

  - project1

    - project1.csproj
  - serialization

    - Folder1

      - *.yml files
    - Folder2

      - *.yml files
    - FolderX

      - *.yml Files ...

and so on. The structructure under the serialization Folder is "dynamic" and files and folders getting added automatically.

At the moment I need to add the new files and folders directly in the source control explorer by adding new items to the TFS and selecting the serialization folder and the next time when new files and folders are added I need to do this again, ....

Is it possible to say the TFs that i should include all Files and Folders in directory "serialization"?

Comment: See my anwser below, we can't use local work spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use [local workspaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace); any files added to the mapped workspace will appear a special "Detected:  added files" heading under the Pending Changes pane of the Team Explorer, which can then be promoted to include in your pending changes.

Comment: I can't use local work spaces, because we have so many files in our workspaces it gets toooo slow when I switch to local work space